# simulated onclick wont refresh listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that should refresh when it recieve an xmpp message. I could see it receiving through Log, but it wont refresh my list view. I can refresh it by pressing a button MANUALLY (which is not ideal, but working fine, it refreshes my listview) with this code

```
btnRefresher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mNotifier = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                    crBroadcast.requery();
                    Log.e("SQLite", "SIMULATED CLICK");
                   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            };

        }
        });
```

When I receive an xmpp message i just use this code, which simulates a button press

```
btnRefresher.performClick();
```

When that happens, I could see the log message "SIMULATED CLICK", which is fine.. its just that it wont do the other codes on it, which is

```
crBroadcast.requery();

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please help! thanks people

Comment: Add log in first line of your onClick method as well to see if it's onClick that's not being called or the handler inside.

Comment: Thanks Sharj for your time and response. but I tried your suggestion, I was able to call both

Comment: Where did you refresh the mAdapter's Data?

Comment: a) Why are you using a handler? b) You just defined handler and not calling it anywhere so it will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on yours `ListView`instance insted of adapter:

```
((ADAPTERS_CLASS_NAME)mListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: hi mohax, thanks for your time and response, but I think that call is not available, as I get this error `The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter` for the code `mListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`